# how to neglect Mandatory column fields while saving record?

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have created a record through suitelet. and in the end I m doing :

```
    oppRec.save({
      enableSourcing: true,
      ignoreMandatoryFields: true
    });
```

But the mandatory column field(in the record i m generating) are not getting ignored and script is throwing error while saving the `oppRec`. Can anyone guide me what wrong m I doing?

Answer (score 2):

The ignoreMandatory field options does not ignore mandatory fields in the record.  There are some fields in the record that are mandatory because they are needed for the system to function correctly, e.g. if you have Location based inventory management, the Location field cannot be blank.

From NS help:

[image]

If you read the error message, it should indicate which fields will need to be populated

Comment: but when i m trying to setValue in the location field, system throws me an error:
"You have entered an Invalid Field Value 461 for the following field: location"
Although 461 is a valid location id.